Issue with nvidia drivers & with dpkg
I am trying to run the software MinKnow on my Linux device (ubuntu 22.04). This is a GUI based program for DNA sequence analysis, and is giving an error "Post-run basecalling is currently unavailable. Please restart your device and then try again." and "No workflows found" when I try to run my analysis.
To troubleshoot this I began by checking my nvidia drivers are installed properly, following this thread I ran:
dkms status

and I got:
nvidia/535.183.01, 5.15.0-112-generic, x86_64: installed

Based on the aforementioned thread, I concluded that I likely have the same headers issue, and proceeded to download all of the module and header .deb files from here. When I navigate to the folder they are contained in (downloads) try to run:
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

I get this output:
(Reading database ... 317785 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack docker-desktop-4.30.0-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-desktop (4.30.0-149282) over (4.30.0-149282) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-6.7.2-060702_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.7.2-060702 (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) over (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) over (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) over (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) ...
dpkg: error processing archive linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_armhf.deb (--install):
 package architecture (armhf) does not match system (amd64)
dpkg: error processing archive linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_ppc64el.deb (--install):
 package architecture (ppc64el) does not match system (amd64)
dpkg: error processing archive linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_s390x.deb (--install):
 package architecture (s390x) does not match system (amd64)
dpkg: regarding teamviewer-host_15.54.3_amd64.deb containing teamviewer-host:
 teamviewer-host conflicts with teamviewer
  teamviewer (version 15.54.3) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive teamviewer-host_15.54.3_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing teamviewer-host
Setting up docker-desktop (4.30.0-149282) ...
Enabling use of privileged ports by Docker Desktop
kubernetes.docker.internal already in /etc/hosts
Reloading systemd daemon for logged in users
Done reloading systemd daemon for logged in users
Setting up linux-headers-6.7.2-060702 (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic:
 linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.38); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.35-0ubuntu3.8.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_armhf.deb
 linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_ppc64el.deb
 linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_s390x.deb
 teamviewer-host_15.54.3_amd64.deb
 linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic

This has a number of errors which I am not sure how to interpret, and when I continue to run:
sudo dkms build nvidia/535.183.01

I get this:
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 6.9.3-060903-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-6.9.3-060903-generic package or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.

I found a number of options telling me to upgrade te kernel headers but when I run these I get a similar output, example command:
sudo apt install linux-generic

Output:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 linux-generic : Depends: linux-image-generic (= 5.15.0.112.112) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.8 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

I have ran:
sudo apt fix-broken install

This gives:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libwpe-1.0-1 libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 28.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 317785 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) ...

After this I repeated:
sudo apt install linux-generic

Which now gives:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libwpe-1.0-1 libwpebackend-fdo-1.0-1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-5.15.0-112-generic linux-image-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-112-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-112-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.15.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-generic linux-image-5.15.0-112-generic linux-image-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-112-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-112-generic
0 to upgrade, 5 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
Need to get 98.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 480 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-5.15.0-112-generic amd64 5.15.0-112.122 [22.6 MB]
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-image-5.15.0-112-generic amd64 5.15.0-112.122 [11.5 MB]
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-112-generic amd64 5.15.0-112.122 [63.9 MB]
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 5.15.0.112.112 [2,510 B]
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 5.15.0.112.112 [1,692 B]
Fetched 98.1 MB in 1min 35s (1,028 kB/s)                                       
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.15.0-112-generic.
(Reading database ... 307611 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-5.15.0-112-generic_5.15.0-112.122_amd64.de
b ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.15.0-112-generic (5.15.0-112.122) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-5.15.0-112-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.15.0-112-generic_5.15.0-112.122_amd64.deb 
...
Unpacking linux-image-5.15.0-112-generic (5.15.0-112.122) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-112-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-112-generic_5.15.0-112.122_am
d64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-112-generic (5.15.0-112.122) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_5.15.0.112.112_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (5.15.0.112.112) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic_5.15.0.112.112_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (5.15.0.112.112) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.15.0-112-generic (5.15.0-112.122) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.5.0-41-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.15.0-112-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.15.0-112-generic
Setting up linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-112-generic (5.15.0-112.122) ...
Setting up linux-modules-5.15.0-112-generic (5.15.0-112.122) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (5.15.0.112.112) ...
Setting up linux-generic (5.15.0.112.112) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.15.0-112-generic (5.15.0-112.122) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-112-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-112-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.9.3-060903-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.9.3-060903-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-112-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-112-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

When I now return to:
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

I get a similar output:
(Reading database ... 314838 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack docker-desktop-4.30.0-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-desktop (4.30.0-149282) over (4.30.0-149282) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-6.7.2-060702_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.7.2-060702 (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) over (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) over (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) ...
dpkg: error processing archive linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_armhf.deb (--install):
 package architecture (armhf) does not match system (amd64)
dpkg: error processing archive linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_ppc64el.deb (--install):
 package architecture (ppc64el) does not match system (amd64)
dpkg: error processing archive linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_s390x.deb (--install):
 package architecture (s390x) does not match system (amd64)
dpkg: regarding teamviewer-host_15.54.3_amd64.deb containing teamviewer-host:
 teamviewer-host conflicts with teamviewer
  teamviewer (version 15.54.3) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive teamviewer-host_15.54.3_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing teamviewer-host
Setting up docker-desktop (4.30.0-149282) ...
Enabling use of privileged ports by Docker Desktop
kubernetes.docker.internal already in /etc/hosts
Reloading systemd daemon for logged in users
Done reloading systemd daemon for logged in users
Setting up linux-headers-6.7.2-060702 (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic:
 linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.38); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.35-0ubuntu3.8.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic (6.7.2-060702.202401251943) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_armhf.deb
 linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_ppc64el.deb
 linux-modules-6.7.2-060702-generic_6.7.2-060702.202401251943_s390x.deb
 teamviewer-host_15.54.3_amd64.deb
 linux-headers-6.7.2-060702-generic

and when I run
sudo dkms build nvidia/535.183.01

it still gives
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 6.9.3-060903-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-6.9.3-060903-generic package or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located.

I am a little stuck for what I should be doing here, I think I still need to resolve the headers issue bit I am not sure what I need to do. can anyone help?

What version of Ubuntu are you using?  Also, 6.9.3-060903-generic is a mainline Kernel and not found in the default Ubuntu repositories.  You can download and install it from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.9.3/  Please remember that mainline Kernels have not been released into the default repositories of Ubuntu and can be full of bugs.  You are more than welcome to file any bugs you find with those Kernels directly with Canonical.

Sorry I will edit and add this to the post, Ubuntu 22.04

Does it matter which build I select?

You need to download and install the headers from the mainline site.  Your error message of Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 6.9.3-060903-generic cannot be found. is showing that it is not found but yet your next command of installing the linux-generic will only pull from the repositories and not from the mainline page.  You will basically need all 4 of the .deb files from the AMD64 section of the mainline site or at least the 2 header files.

Great thank you, and then I can repeat sudo dpkg -i *.deb?

Yes, that is how you install them.  Make sure to put them in their own directory before you run that command just in case there are other .deb files in that same directory you downloaded them to.

Great thank you that has worked! I now get this error when attempting sudo dkms build nvidia/535.183.01,
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/535.183.01/build/make.log for more information.```
This log file contains this error ```cc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-ftrivial-auto-var-init=zero’```

There is a chance that version for the video card driver is not compatible with that Kernel version.  Look into installing the HWE Kernels instead.  The current Kernel version for 22.04 LTS with HWE enabled is 6.5.0-41-generic.

Thanks I will try this, how would I install specifically this version?

is this correct? https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.5-rc7/

You will need the same compiler available for the Nvidia driver build as was used for the kernel (gcc-13? 14?). Does the driver build script use such a compiler if present or do you have to fiddle with links to (temporarily for the build) change the default compiler? It's much easier to stick with the offerings from the Ubuntu repositories, which work at least for the hwe 6.5 kernels on 22.04 for Nvidia driver 535.

To install the HWE Kernel for 22.04 it is sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04.  Then reboot your system and select that Kernel version.  You might have to go through and remove the other Kernels that you may have installed after you are booted to the 6.5.0-41-generic Kernel.

Thanks Terrance. I was just using sudo apt purge to remove the other kernels. When I try to remove the kernel I am currently booted on I get a big purple warning message, warning it could break the install. If I still have this kernel installed will it automatically boot on the only available one, or is there another step I should take before removing the currently installed kernel?

Just to double check this, this is the list if installed Kernels linux-headers-6.5.0-41-generic linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-image-unsigned-6.9.3-060903-generic linux-modules-6.5.0-41-generic linux-modules-6.9.3-060903-generic linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-41-generic. Prior to running sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04 al I had installed were the two 6.9.3 kernels, which I am currently booted in (and left installed due to the above mentioned warning message). Am I removing all kernels except hwe-22.04?

Just to follow up, I was able to resolve this by booting to the grub menu (following the top answer in this thread and selecting the 6.5.0-41 kernel, then using sudo apt purge to remove 6.9.3. The commands for installation of the nvidia drivers in the thread linked above then worked. The Minknow software is now working! Thanks again for all the help!!
